# Проблема со знаком доллара при создании функции PSQLException

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Столкнулся с проблемой: Есть скрипт инициализации БД в котором создаются функции и триггеры. Функция выглядит примерно так:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION function_name()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$trigger$
BEGIN
  <FUNCTION BODY>
END;
$trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

При запуске скрипта из идеи скрипт отрабатывает корректно: создаются все таблицы, функции и триггеры, но при инициализации контекста спринга скрипт выбрасывает исключение:

```
...org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position...
```

По всей видимости, ругается на знаки доллара в теле функции. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и подскажет как её решить или обойти.
Полный текст исключения:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #63 of class path resource [db/initDB.sql]: CREATE FUNCTION function_name() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $trigger$ BEGIN <FUNCTION BODY>; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 50 in SQL CREATE FUNCTION function_name() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $new_emp$ BEGIN <FUNCTION BODY>. Expected terminating $$
```

Название функции, триггера и тело функции опустил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Твоя функция написана корректно с точки зрения postgres-синтаксиса. Скорее всего у  тебя проблема с sql-клиентом (укажи какой используешь). Твой sql-клиент **бьёт запрос со своей стороны по знаку точка с запятой**, т.е. на выходе он как бы отдаёт в базу два разных sql-запроса. Тебе надо указать в настройках **другой символ разделитель**. Чтобы не быть голословным приведу тебе пример, воспроизводящий твою ошибку **с твоим запросом**.

Вот собственно [он](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/466d9):

[image: Ошибка]

Обрати внимание на то, что в качестве разделителя используется точка с запятой, а ошибка получается точно такая же.

А теперь, после смены знака-разделителя на вертикальную черту [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/860a5) прекрасно исполняется:

[image: Успех]

Comment: Возможно глупый вопрос, но как узнать версию SQL-клиента? К чему вообще это относится? И как можно изменить символ разделитель.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГлушаков SQL-клиент это приложение, в котором ты набиваешь запрос. Примеры клиентов : pgAdmin, SqlDeveloper, HeidiSQL PHPMyAdmin, dbForge Studio,  SQLyog и т.д. Соответственно для каждого клиента настройки выставляются по-своему.

Comment: Дело в том что запрос выполняет Spring.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГлушаков, тогда покажи пример вызова внутри кода

Comment: Скрипт вызывается инициализатором БД из файла конфигурации. Есть в моём ответе. В инициализаторе я указываю путь скрипту, а спринг сам его запускает.

Comment: Тёмка, большое спасибо, твой ответ был очень полезен и натолкнул на решение.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему удалось решить добавив

```
separator=";;"
```

в инициализатор базы данных файла конфигурации Spring:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${database.init}" separator=";;" >
    <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="classpath:db/${jdbc.initLocation}"/>        
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

а в скрипт инициализации, в конец последнего оператора поставить не одиночную точку с запятой, а двойную:

```
NSERT INTO edit_types (id, code) VALUES
(1, 'CREATE'),
(2, 'UPDATE'),
(3, 'DELETE');;
```

Работает если поставить в конце любого другого оператора, но мне показалось, что лучше в конце. Если я правильно понял: запрос разбивается куски разделенные ";;" и в данном случае он отправляет скрипт одним куском. А если убрать из запроса ";;" то спринг разбивает запрос непонятным мне образом и вылетает ошибка синтаксиса. Что касается знаков доллара, то они функция где они используются должна быть в одном куске скрипта. Я правильно понял? И грозят ли мне какие-нибудь сайд эффекты?

Comment: По дефолту указанная конструкция разбивает запросы по знаку точка с запятой. См [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils#DEFAULT_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html#DEFAULT_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR)

Comment: Тёмка, большое спасибо. Если я правильно понимаю, то проблем у меня быть не должно, теперь скрипт не разбивается.